# Клик по ссылке после загрузки страницы на JS

Tags: javascript

Помогите с JS-ом.
Нужен JS код который будет кликать на ссылку после загрузги страницы

У меня таб на айах. Нужна чтобы если загрузка страницы закончился, был автоматический клик на таб "Graphic".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Извините а не подскажите как это пишется? Где я должен установить код?

Comment: Я разместил в head, но не работает

Comment: <script>

$(document).ready(function() { $('[data-filter=".graphic"]').click(); })

</script>

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Ответ в соответствии с вопросом</sup>

[image]

Вместо `...style.visibility = 'hidden'` с тем же успехом может выполняться `myElement.click();`, или вообще любое выражение... а таймер - естественно, опционален.